# Python: Trouble with encoding on Windows (Bokeh plotting library)

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, bokeh

I am trying to reproduce the simplest examples from the [Bokeh tutorial](http://bokeh.pydata.org/tutorial/basic.html), on a 64-bit Windows machine with Python 3.3.0.

Here is the code in its entirety

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

# NOTE need this import as output_file was not getting imported into the 
#     global namespace
import bokeh.plotting as bkp
from bokeh.plotting import *

# Skip the first point because it can be troublesome
theta = np.linspace(0, 8*np.pi, 10000)[1:]

# Compute the radial coordinates for some different spirals
lituus = theta**(-1/2)          # lituus
golden = np.exp(0.306349*theta) # golden
arch   = theta                  # Archimedean
fermat = theta**(1/2)           # Fermat's

# Now compute the X and Y coordinates (polar mappers planned for Bokeh later)
golden_x = golden*np.cos(theta)
golden_y = golden*np.sin(theta)
lituus_x = lituus*np.cos(theta)
lituus_y = lituus*np.sin(theta)
arch_x   = arch*np.cos(theta)
arch_y   = arch*np.sin(theta)
fermat_x = fermat*np.cos(theta)
fermat_y = fermat*np.sin(theta)

# output to static HTML file
bkp.output_file("lines.html")

# Plot the Archimedean spiral using the `line` renderer. Note how we set the
# color, line thickness, title, and legend value.
line(arch_x, arch_y, color="red", line_width=2, title="Archimean", legend="Archimedean")
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\programming\python\python64\python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2732, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-00be3b4eba05>", line 1, in <module>
    bkp.line(arch_x, arch_y, color="red", line_width=2, title="Archimean", legend="Archimedean")
  File "F:\programming\python\python64\python33\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting.py", line 318, in wrapper
    save()
  File "F:\programming\python\python64\python33\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting.py", line 284, in save
    f.write(html)
  File "F:\programming\python\python64\python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1831286-1831289: character maps to <undefined>
```

I understand that this has something to do with the encoding that Python is using to write to the output file, but don't know enough about setting the encoding of the output file or the encoding that is being used by Python to write out to fix this. Help appreciated.

### Edit:

I tried to implement the advice given [here](http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Encoding_of_Python_stdout), to always pass stdout output through a streamwriter:

```
if sys.stdout.encoding != 'UTF-8':
    sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout.buffer, 'strict')
if sys.stderr.encoding != 'UTF-8':
    sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stderr.buffer, 'strict')
```

but some of the interface appears to have changed, and there is no `sys.stdout.encoding` variable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\programming\python\python64\python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2732, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-e12310bc7a07>", line 1, in <module>
    if sys.stdout.encoding != 'UTF-8':
  File "F:\programming\python\python64\python33\lib\codecs.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.stream, name)
AttributeError: '_io.FileIO' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to `sys.stdout`, but if you want to replace it in Python 3, use `sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), 'utf-8', 'strict')`.

Comment: [`bokeh.plotting.save`](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/plotting.py#L248) doesn't set the encoding for the file. It uses the default from [`locale.getprefferedencoding`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding). I'm afraid to use this you'd need to either monkey patch `bokeh.plotting` or `locale` (`_bootlocale` in 3.4).

Comment: @eryksun Hmm, I did a search for `getprefferedencoding` in the bokeh directory, and it does not seem to have been used. Can you point me to the lines of code where I can explicitly set the output enconding?

Comment: `open(filename, "w")` implicitly uses `getprefferedencoding` if you don't provide an explicit `encoding` such as `open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: @eryksun So just add `encoding='utf-8'` option?

Comment: @eryksun Yeah, now I am trying to find the lines to modify. Help appreciated. :)

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the pointer, found it. Wonder why this is not an option for `output_file`.

Comment: @eryksun Also, if you put your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this problem on a windows 8 VM, can you give some more information here (or in the GH issue below) about what your system locale, etc. is?

Comment: @bigreddot, the traceback shows codepage 1252. `getpreferredencoding` calls `_locale._getdefaultlocale`, which calls the Windows API [`GetACP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: OK, how can I configure a windows 8 machine to use cp1252? I don't see anything under language/locale settings. Thanks

Comment: @bigreddot, in Windows 7 changing the system locale is on the administrative tab for the region and language settings. You can check the current value using ctypes: `import ctypes; print(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetACP())`.

Comment: Looks like it is already using cp1252 so I am not sure why we can't reproduce this:

In [1]: import ctypes; print(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetACP())
1252

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have opened an issue to track this problem: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/issues/682

As you have discussed with eryksun, it seems easily fixable.

I will keep you updated here, but if you want to participate in the issue, you are very welcome.

Cheers

Comment: As you have resolved this on github, I am marking this the accepted answer. Interesting dalliance with `wontfix` though.

Answer (score 1):

fg nu,

We can not replicate the issue in our win platforms... can you please join us in the opened issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/issues/682 to get more information about your setup and architecture?

We will very grateful if you can give us more info to replicate the issue and get a quick fix.

Thanks.

Damian

Comment: I tried this in Windows with `cp1252`, and it worked without error. For some reason fg nu's output has a character that can't be encoded in `cp1252`. But really, being limited to an 8-bit code page that has 250 characters is straight out of the last century. The output file needs an option to set the encoding and a cross-platform default of UTF-8.

Comment: We are currently discussing this issue. An optional encoding could be problematic because the Bokeh content can not be encoded with all the encoding options available. But we are evaluating the possibility to default to UTF-8 as you mentioned.