# Python: Trouble with encoding on Windows when run bokeh serve (Bokeh plotting library)

Tags: bokeh

I am using Bokeh to create an interactive plot ,when I run

`boken serve myapp.py`

I got the

`'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 2196: illegal multibyte sequencencoding`

I understood this is related to codec issue as I have been using Chinese character there. There is [a similar discussion in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075840/python-trouble-with-encoding-on-windows-bokeh-plotting-library) . However here I was not able to use the `output_file` to set the encoding as here in my case `curdoc` was needed instead.How can I fix this issue? I am using a Window machine with Chinese character support, have tried `chcp 65001`, it does not work either.

Comment: There's probably some work to do in core Bokeh to make this function. I'd suggest making a GH issue with complete details (i.e. a full sample code that reproduces the problem) and being available to help test. None of the core devs really use windows, or have much experience with non-UTF8 encodings, so to get this fixed will require collaboration with someone who does .

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Hope this will help.

The problem is in `site-packages\bokeh\application\handlers\script.py` line 53. I think this uses the default codec of windows (eg. 'gbk').

If you make sure your `myapp.py` is saved in `utf8-without-bom`, and then change this line to:

`with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:`

It should work.

Comment: Perhaps some small changes to make this more configurable would help users. Please feel free to open a GitHub issue (or pull request)

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: After some more digging into the source code, there are so many places using 'utf-8', I couldn't make this configurable. So maybe the most easy way is still like in my answerto make sure the scripts are saved in 'utf-8' format, and open it in 'utf-8' format.